# Swift convert UInt to Int

Tags: integer, swift, uint32

I have this expression which returns a `UInt32`:

```
let randomLetterNumber = arc4random()%26
```

I want to be able to use the number in this if statement:

```
if letters.count > randomLetterNumber{
    var randomLetter = letters[randomLetterNumber]
}
```

This issue is that the console is giving me this

```
Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:11:18: error: could not find an overload for '>' that accepts the supplied arguments
if letters.count > randomLetterNumber{
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The problem is that `UInt32` cannot be compared to an `Int`. I want to cast `randomLetterNumber` to an `Int`. I have tried:

```
let randomLetterUNumber : Int = arc4random()%26
let randomLetterUNumber = arc4random()%26 as Int
```

These both cause `could not find an overload for '%' that accepts the supplied arguments.`

How can I cast the value or  use it in the if statement?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`Int(arc4random_uniform(26))` does two things, one it eliminates the negative results from your current method and second should correctly creat an Int from the result.

Comment: Thanks for that, the Int() initializer seems to do the trick.

Comment: You can read more about numeric type conversion in **[Apple's Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_420)**.

Comment: Thanks.  I had a similar problem with arc4random_uniform(someArray.count)
casting fixes the problem arc4random_uniform(UInt32(someArray.count))

Comment: I had both problems:       probability = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(total))) … the main problem is because of the headers the type-ahead doesn't have info on this method and doesn't provide the needed metadata (which it would then offer as suggestions to fix the problem)

Answer (score 25):

More simple than this, impossible:

```
Int(myUInteger)
```

Comment: This does the exact opposite of what OP asked. Should be `Int(myUInteger)`

Comment: this suddenly start giving me "Not enough bits to represent the passed value" more specifically Int(arc4random())

Answer (score 11):

Just create a new int with it

```
let newRandom: Int = Int(randomLetterNumber)
if letters.count > newRandom {
    var randomLetter = letters[newRandom]
}
```

or if you never care about the UInt32 you can just create an 
Int immediately:

```
let randomLetterNumber = Int(arc4random() % 26)
```

Comment: Note that this will throw an exception half the time due to overflow checking, use the answer I gave to avoid that.

Comment: @David, how so? Not disagreeing, just want to understand what you mean.

Comment: Actually it won't since you're doing the casting after the modulo, so you can guarantee it's always in bounds.  `Int(arc4random())` will crash 50% of the time it's executed on a 32-bit platform because a UInt32 won't fit in an Int32.  Just seen too many "arc4random is bugged and crashes" questions with swift.  In any case arc4random_uniform will give a more uniform distribution.

Comment: Modifying/bounding the output of a random number distribution with modulo or division operations is poor form: it ruins the distribution properties that the functions guarantee. Instead, use `arc4random_uniform(26)` to let the function uphold a uniform distribution across the range you specify.

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
let u: UInt32 = 0x1234abcd
let s: Int32 = Int32(bitPattern: u)
```