# Swift mastermind

Tags: swift

I try to make a Mastermind in swift but I can't get each digit of the random number using an index to check if I found a number of the code.
I tried this but it's not works.. :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    var code = String(arc4random_uniform(9000) + 1000)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(code)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func sendDidPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        var find = 0

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            var number = textField.text
            var numberInCode = map(code) { String($0) }

            if contains(numberInCode, String(find)) {
                find++
            }

            self.textView.text = "\(self.textField.text): Bien placées: \(String(find))"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func resetCode(sender: AnyObject) {

    }
}
```

I need help

Comment: What are you trying in your code? It doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: It appears that he is trying to get each digit of the 4 digit random number individually.

Comment: Changed the answer, this should get what you want

Comment: Please be clear on what you mean by "not works." What precisely do you expect to happen? What precisely does happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get each digit of the random number individually:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var code = [String]()
    let textFromField = "1" // Text from your textField

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let number = String(arc4random_uniform(9000) + 1000)
        code = map(number) { String($0) }
    }

    @IBAction func sendDidPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        for index in 0..<code.count {
            if textFromField == code[index] {
                println("Match found at index: \(index + 1)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`code` is now an `Array` with the numbers separated as `Strings`

You should change the way you convert the random number to Int because according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144557/swift-convert-uint-to-int):

> `Int(arc4random())` will crash 50% of the time it's executed on a 32-bit platform because a UInt32 won't fit in an Int32

EDIT: Simplified things

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want, but you should be able to get what you need with this example

Comment: Can you explain me what you did ?

Comment: First, you generate a random number, convert the number to `String` and store it in `code`. `map()` converts `code` to an array of type `String` and store it in `separated`. Now you have an array and can try to check if the array contains `find` using `contains()`.

Comment: Now it will iterate through the array of "numbers" and check if the "number" of your textfield matches with any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the random number into an array of characters,

```
var code = (arc4random_uniform() % 9000 + 1000)  //e.g. 1245
var codeAsArray = Array(String(code))    //e.g. [1, 2, 4, 5]

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   // var number = textField.text

    println(codeAsArray[i]) //is a swift Character
}
```